# Grails App - Unable to create initial connections of pool

Tags: oracle, grails, jdbc

When trying to run my grails app, I get this error:

```
    ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Now I know I most likely just need to copy the jdbc jar file into my grails app. But where exactly do I copy it to? I don't have an applications/lib directory in my project. I have build/libs. Or would it go somewhere in my .posh_gvm/grails folder?

My `application.yml` has this:

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the dependency (and driver location) in your Gradle configuration. Place the file somewhere in your project directory (e.g. for the example snippet below, create a directory called `lib` at the project root), and add it to your class path in your `build.gradle` file in your `buildscript` config (under the `dependencies` section):

```
 buildscript {

    dependencies {

       classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
       classpath files('/lib/ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar')
```

Then add your `lib` directory to your `repositories`:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    //...
    flatDir {dirs 'lib'}
```

And finally include the driver in your `dependencies` section:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.oracle:ojdbc7'
```

Comment: just did exactly that and got the same error. Created a lib folder directly under project root, stashed my ojdbc6.jar file in there, and added those lines to my dependencies section in build.gradle.

Comment: Try adding your `lib` directory to your `repositories` section: `repositories {/*...*/
    flatDir {dirs 'lib'}` (just updated the answer)

Comment: So something like this? `repositories {
        flatdir {dirs 'lib'}
    }`

Comment: Yeah, add it to your other repositories in that section of `build.gradle`.

Comment: Now the compile errors out saying cannot find method flatdir()

Comment: Any other ideas here Zach?

Comment: The exact same error? Still unable to load the class?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I confused the buildscript/dependencies with the top-level dependencies section. See updated answer. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110552/discussion-between-zacharyaklein-and-andrew).